# Serenity index.html

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to add the application version number that is displayed in the login page in the serenity report. Currently I am just capturing it in the code and printing in the console. Is there anyway the console output can be included in the serenity index.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following property of Serenity:

```
serenity.project.name
```

It displays a project name in the top-right corner of the test case report (not the main Serenity page though). I have not tried this, but you might override that property each time you run prior to when Serenity kicks in. Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Alternatively, you could provide a `final String` with version to a test case tag, e.g. with `@WithTag` or `@WithTags` or `@WithTagValuesOf` annotations. Example:

```
final String version = "1.0";

// ...

@Test
@WithTagValuesOf({ "version:" + version })
// test method here
```

Result:

[image]

Hope you will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

In your `serenity.properties` file you can add:

`report.customfields.ApplicationVersion = 1.2.3`

This will appear on your html summary report towards the top as a custom title, with the version you have specified.